# How to manipulate an array similar to an ORDER BY clause in SQL?

Tags: java, sql, arrays, sql-order-by, processing

My data has been placed into an array, but unfortunately not in the order I want it in...

```
String[][] databaseToArray = {
  //{"Name", "Channel", "Description", "Amount", "isReady"},
    {"John", "Nick",    "likes",       "2",      "yes"    },
    {"Drew", "MTV",     "dislikes",    "4",      "no"     },
    {"Fred", "CNN",     "okay",        "3",      "no"     },
    {"Beth", "Fox",     "valid",       "1",      "yes"    }
};
```

How do I manipulate this array so that when I loop through it the order is by the amount , similar to `SELECT * FROM "databaseToArray" ORDER BY "Amount"` aka

```
String[][] reorganizedArray = {
  //{"Name", "Channel", "Description", "Amount", "isReady"},
    {"Beth", "Fox",     "valid",       "1",      "yes"    },
    {"John", "Nick",    "likes",       "2",      "yes"    },
    {"Fred", "CNN",     "okay",        "3",      "no"     },
    {"Drew", "MTV",     "dislikes",    "4",      "no"     }
};
```

Comment: "Processing.org is based on Java, but because program elements in Processing are fairly simple, you can learn to use it even if you don't know any Java."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to pass a [Comparator](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/collections/comparators.html) to the Arrays.sort method.  I haven't done Java in 5 years, but it should be easily doable.  Maybe someone can clean up this example I'm about to write, since I'm pretty certain I'll get something wrong.

```
String[][] databaseToArray = {
  //{"Name", "Channel", "Description", "Amount", "isReady"},
    {"John", "Nick",    "likes",       "2",      "yes"    },
    {"Drew", "MTV",     "dislikes",    "4",      "no"     },
    {"Fred", "CNN",     "okay",        "3",      "no"     },
    {"Beth", "Fox",     "valid",       "1",      "yes"    }
};

Arrays.sort(databaseToArray, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    public int compare(String[] a, String[] b) {
        return a[3].compareTo(b[3]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the sort method on the processing website, but this is only for One-Dimensional Arrays...

http://processing.org/reference/sort_.html

```
   float[] a = { 3, 5, 2, 4, 1 };
   a = sort(a);
   println(a);
// Prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```